# Error using multiple Generic Classes in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, derived-class

I tried to find a similar issue already posted but simply got confused with what i found.

I have a situation which involves the following objects:-
Reports contain parameters
Documents contain parameters
Report and Document Parameters are similar
Queries contain parameters
Reports, Documents and Queries all have similar Parameters

So I created the following class structure:-

```
Public MustInherit Class clsBaseCollection(Of TclsBaseChild As clsBase, TclsBaseParent As clsBase)

Public MustInherit Class clsParams(Of TclsParam As clsParam, TclsRootObject As clsRootObject)  
    Inherits clsBaseCollection(Of TclsParam, TclsRootObject)

Public MustInherit Class clsRepDocParams(Of TclsRepDocParam As clsRepDocParam, TclsReportDocument As clsReportDocument)  
    Inherits clsParams(Of TclsRepDocParam, TclsReportDocument)

Public Class clsReportParams  
    Inherits clsRepDocParams(Of clsReportParam, clsReport)


Public MustInherit Class clsReportDocument    
    MustOverride ReadOnly Property Parameters() As clsRepDocParams(Of clsRepDocParam,clsReportDocument)

Public Class clsReport  
    Inherits clsReportDocument  
    Private _Params As clsReportParams  
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Parameters() As clsReportParams  
        Get  
            If _Params Is Nothing Then  
                BeginUpdate()  
                _Params = New clsReportParams(Me)  
                EndUpdate()  
            End If  
            Return _Params  
        End Get  
    End Property
```

The last property produces the following error:-

‘Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Parameters As clsReportParams' cannot override 'Public MustOverride ReadOnly Property Parameters As clsRepDocParams(Of clsRepDocParam, clsReportDocument)' because they differ by their return types.

I cant see how this is so because I believe I have my classing levels correct!?

Apologies for the lack of tab formatting... im new to the stack overflow site and hopefully i will improve ;)

Cheers
Jeff

Comment: Please tell us what version of Vb and .Net.

Comment: Visual STudio 2010 pro and dotnet 4 and thanks to Jared for the reformatting...

Answer (score 0):

The MustOverride property is declared as

```
As clsRepDocParams(Of clsRepDocParam,clsReportDocument)
```

Your Override is simply declared as

```
As clsReportParams
```

It does not specify the base collection so they do not match. You should probably declare the override as

```
As clsRepDocParams(Of clsRepDocParam,clsReportDocument)
```

to match the base class.

It is worth noting that with every additional level of inheritance that you create, you need to be that much more careful to ensure that you design is done very carefully! If I was reviewing that code I would need to be convinced that the complexity was actually going to pay off over the lifetime of the project.